# "He's finally joined to the gym" or "He's finally joined the gym"

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct sentence, and why?

> 1. He's finally joined **to** the gym

or

> 2. He's finally joined the gym

If it's the second one, why can't I use "to" after "joined"?

Comment: The second sentence is correct.

Comment: It seems that the verb **join** tends to take the direct object in the majority of cases where the subject is becoming part of something. I found some old texts with sentences like "He joined **to** the spirit of the Lord", but that must be a very dated usage.

Comment: *Joined to* makes it sound as if he has become physically connected to the gym. That might make an interesting science fiction or horror story, but wouldn't sound right in most circumstances.

Comment: Erick's comment expresses exactly how I read it. "joined to" sounds physical where "joined", in this context, does not.

Comment: Re the comment by @ErickG.Hagstrom (with which I agree wholly), "he's joined to the gym" means "he is joined to the gym" whereas "he's joined the gym" means "he has joined the gym".

Comment: Have a look at Oald to see how the verb is constructed. You can join two things or you can join A to B.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/join_1?q=join

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second sentence is correct. When the subject is himself becoming part of something, "join" takes a direct object:

> He's finally joined the gym.
>   He joined the army.

---

When a person or some other actor "joins" some other things, it seems that we can use **to**:

> Check whether you have joined the computer **to** a homegroup.
>
> Remove the check from the box to accept the user who **joined the computer to the domain** and whose name is displayed.

Here, a person joins his computer to a homegroup; a user joins his computer to the domain. The computer does not join a homegroup or the domain under its own will.

Another sentence, from Google Books:

> In 1618, on the death of Duke Albert of Prussia, East Prussia **was finally joined to** the Electorate of Brandenburg. (Albert Seaton, 1973)

We have the passive-voice construction: East Prussia was "joined" by some external will to another state.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct.

> He's finally joined **the gym.**

From [termiumplus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_j&page=9BLguLSG4Mik.html):

> For most purposes, ***join*** is a transitive verb and takes a direct object without any preposition (e.g., *join a club*). Sometimes ***join*** is followed by such prepositions as *in, to, up* and *with* for emphasis. The verb join up specifically indicates becoming a member of an association, a movement or the military.

> Examples:
>
> > - What knot should we use to join the ends of these ropes?

- Sabrina’s friends urged her to join in extracurricular activities at her high school.
- After a few choruses, Ryan was brave enough to join in the singing.
- Mara knows how to join this piece of the quilt to the next.
- The Okanagan Sailing Club is looking for new members. Do you want to join up?
- On this special day, I join with everyone present to wish the newlyweds every happiness.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that both sound correct; and this depends on what one wants to say.

In the first example "joined" looks like an adjective preceded by ‘s which is the short form of "is". Whereas the other sentence ‘s  is the abbreviation of "has" followed by "has" then the past participle of the verb "join" which is joined.

Comment: Both sentences use the present perfect. The only difference between them is the particle "to", that has been highlighted. "He is finally joined to the gym" is not idiomatic.